# Ujquery height arrangement

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am using in my html code the automatic menu accordition of Ujquery.
The site is [here](http://jqueryui.com/accordion/#default)

I managed in my css file to adjust the width of it with the following code:

```
.menu{

    position: absolute;
    top: 5%;
    left: 10%;
    width: 80%;
    background-color: blue;
 }
```

Why the width parametre works great and the height not? I want to set all this menu to 50% of my available space.
Thank you for your time in advance.

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/accordion/#fillspace or http://jqueryui.com/accordion/#no-auto-height

Comment: tried that and dont work!

Answer (score 1):

```
.ui-accordion-content{height:50%;position:relative;}
```

Don't initialize heightStyle at all.

```
  $(function() {
    $( "#accordion" ).accordion({
    });
  });
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/calder12/h8KhV/2/

Comment: then something else is interfering, it works fine in the fiddle.

Comment: Except for the background of the page and the code above there is nothing more to interfere.

Answer (score 1):

If you are just trying to get the accordion to fill a given amount of space on your page. Try this-

http://jsfiddle.net/apaul34208/GxVYN/1/

js

```
 $(function () {
     $("#accordion").accordion({
         heightStyle: "fill"
     });
 });
```

css

```
body {
    height:500px;
}
.container {
    height:50%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your time.

I solve it following the code [here](http://jqueryui.com/accordion/#fillspace):

Was my mistake not to look all the javascript documentation!
Thank you for you time once more!